# How to edit an element.style?

Tags: html, css

*Problem*: Not able to edit/code an element.style on a page in the following coding language:

**HTML/CSS**

I use an extension called **Stylus** (which is an extension that can edit the pages existing content),
I wanted to edit a buttons dropdown bar, which is shown in the picture below surrounded by a red circle.
[Drop Down Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ0rD.png%5D)

The problem is that the code I'm using is not in any way affecting the element.style, here is some details in the pictures on how my stuff works.

[The Code Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fjY4.png)

[My Code I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCHch.png)

Now it does show on the snippet here that the element.style is applied.
[Applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQutw.png)

But then when I click the pages edit button it changes. [Snippet of Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoM6d.png). It seems to be overridden, I don't know what type of kind of loop I should apply if that's the case.

```
element.style {
  background-color: rgb(255 255 255);
  border-color: white
}
```

To let you know I'm a beginner at coding, my apologies on not knowing what some things may, or may not be called or function.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. First of, are you the developer of the webpage?

Comment: No I'm not the developer of that webpage, I'm a website modder, not in any way associated with the developers of Roblox.com

Comment: So, whats the point of wanting to edit the webpage. Just so you know, some functions might be disabled from the backend and might take more than CSS to enable them. Please checkout https://w3schools.com for tutorials on HTML, CSS, JavaScript and an overview of how these 3 works. Cheers.

Comment: I'll check them out, oh and the point of wanting to edit the webpage was that I've been working on a project of modding the entire roblox website (including over 500+ web pages), and giving it a clean and elegant style, and over 400+ have been done. Since I cannot bare the look of the original page. I'll keep this into mind, while your here do you have any idea on where I can learn looping for css, I'm guessing this w3schools.com has it?

Comment: w3Schools surely has all you'll need to be up and running in CSS. Don't really get what you meant by looping though, as CSS isn't a programming language but a style sheet.